# Unable to set the Make Read Only Custom Rule for Field Type Boolean in Azure DevOps (Process Template)

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem, azure-boards

Am working in creation of Process template and rules for the work item types in Azure DevOps Boards.
I had checklist defined as **Test Case Executed = True or false in Boolean type**.
Where users must fulfill this condition to true to move the user story state from test to staging.

Now to protect this field am trying to create a custom rule for this Boolean Type field by defining if current user is not a member of this group then make read only = Test Case Executed field
But this rule doesn’t work even after creating this rule am getting error as: Test case executed field was empty and there should be value.

Hence i cannot lock this fields any way, please help me in any other possible ways/suggestions to lock this Field (Required).

- Tried Creating multiple groups and set the rule Where Current user is not a member of group = (groupname)
  Then Make Read Only = Test Case Executed.
- Even Tried with other Fields (Multi Value Picker Instead of boolean ) but same Issue.
  I was able to lock the fields but whenever i create a new work item locked field throws an Error:Test case executed field was empty and there should be value.
- Also was unable to edit the required value for boolean field
  [image][image]

Help me with the solution/Other Suggestions to lock the custom field for Boolean Type as this is required for Client.

Comment: You're trying to replicate the behaviour of Test Plans in a custom work item rule, which is unnecessary. Look at how to use Test Plans properly, and you will see you can mark a test step/suite as run from the Execute tab.

Comment: Not Test Plans, Actually am trying to create a custom rule to Lock Boolean Fields (Which doesn't work Properly , Error: Explained )
Ex: Test TC Executed is one of boolean field which i was created So once that field was set to True , User Story can moved to next state.

Comment: Are you familiar with the baked-in process for the Agile template, around test plans and stories? I feel you're trying to bend ADO to your will, when you don't need to.